# hide uncited bibitems in the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I have a shared bibliography.tex file with a set of bibitems:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{A} A
\bibitem{B} B
\end{thebibliography}
```

I have a series of tex files that include this file, each of which produces an output pdf. They are compiled with pdflatex. Their content:

```
\begin{document}
%...
\cite{A} %A or B is cited here
\end{document}
```

I'd like to exclude from the bibliography of the output pdf files those bibitems (in the example A or B) that were not cited in the specific source tex file.

Is there an easy way that does not require going through the pain of bash scripting or compiling with bibtex?

Comment: not really so easy/reliable, there is a reason most people compile bibliographies with bibtex or biber possible of course but the details probably depend on what citation packages you are using and are complicated by the fact that the list syntax doesn't have a definite terminator for each list item

Comment: Welcome TeX.SX! Using `bib` files and `bibtex` or `biber` is the best way to deal with this and will open up more functionality for you.

Comment: You are asking: how can I do X easily without using any of the tools designed to make doing X easy? ;) That is never going to be *less* painful...

Answer (score 1):

I had to chances but to use bibtex plus cite package and adding the references like this:

```
\nocite{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{../../common/bibliography}
```

The nocite command discards all the bibliography not explicitly cited. No need for biblatex package metioned around and no use of theblibliography command which did not discard uncited stuff.